# The functions cosf_neon and sinf_neon in the math neon libary will return the same values?

Tags: assembly, arm, cross-compiling, neon

I have ported the math neon library to my platform. But when running the test code math_debug and I have added cosf_neon and sinf_neon in this sample, they will return the same values. Just like that(These code is added in the test code in the math-neon library):

```
printf("cosf neon result is %f\n", cosf_neon(0.366519));
printf("sinf neon result is %f\n", sinf_neon(0.366519));
```

the results of these two functions are both 0.358367. But the cos and sin in C library will return different values. The correct value of cosf_neon is 0.933580, the correct value of sinf_neon is 0.358368.

The cosf_neon fucntion is :

```
#define sinf_neon       sinf_neon_sfp
#define cosf_neon       cosf_neon_sfp

float cosf_neon_hfp(float x)
{
#ifdef __MATH_NEON
    float xx = x + M_PI_2;
    return sinf_neon_hfp(xx);
#endif
}

float cosf_neon_sfp(float x)
{
#ifdef __MATH_NEON
    asm volatile ("vdup.f32 d0, r0      \n\t");
    cosf_neon_hfp(x);
    asm volatile ("vmov.f32 r0, s0      \n\t");
#else
    return cosf_c(x);
#endif
}
```

The makefile is like that:

```
CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
AR=arm-linux-androideabi-ar
LD=arm-linux-androideabi-ld

CFLAGS := -O2 -ggdb -mcpu=cortex-a7 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -ansi -std=gnu99 -pedantic
WARNINGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wmissing-prototypes
ASSEMBLER := -Wa,-mimplicit-it=thumb

override CFLAGS += $(WARNINGS) $(ASSEMBLER)
LIBS := -lm

all: math_debug

libmathneon.a: math_acosf.o math_ldexpf.o math_powf.o math_sqrtfv.o \
    math_asinf.o math_expf.o math_log10f.o math_runfast.o math_tanf.o \
    math_atan2f.o math_fabsf.o math_logf.o math_sincosf.o math_tanhf.o \
    math_atanf.o math_floorf.o math_mat2.o math_sinf.o math_vec2.o \
    math_ceilf.o math_fmodf.o math_mat3.o math_sinfv.o math_vec3.o \
    math_cosf.o math_frexpf.o math_mat4.o math_sinhf.o math_vec4.o \
    math_coshf.o math_invsqrtf.o math_modf.o math_sqrtf.o

math_debug: math_debug.o libmathneon.a
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
%.o:: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
%.a::
    $(AR) rcs $@ $^
clean:
    $(RM) -v math_debug *.o *.a
```

The math-neon library is downloaded from website [ https://code.google.com/archive/p/math-neon/source/default/source][1]

Looking forward to getting some advice.

Comment: That's a (very nearly) correct value for `sin`, very close to the correctly-rounded result, if it isn't exactly.  But the correct value for `cos(0.366519)` is 0.9335804777, so it's not just rounding error there.  If *you* ported these NEON functions like you say in the question, then you did it wrong, and you should debug `cosf_neon`.  What exactly did you do to port the NEON math library?  And how are you compiling / linking this code, and with what compiler?

Comment: Yes, the return value sin_neon is right, but cos_neon is wrong. And I have call sinf_neon with the parameter (0.366519+pi/2), the value is correct.I compile math neon library using NDK

Comment: Which NEON math library are you using, and is it even supposed to work for scalars instead of vectors?  How did you change it when you ported it?  Your question is not a [mcve], not even close!

Comment: Sorry. I got the math-neon library from https://code.google.com/archive/p/math-neon/source/default/source. I compile this library using NDK toolchain and I didn't modify other code except the sample code(math_debug.c, and I only add the code that call cosf_neon and sinf_neon) in this library.The version of NDK is r14b.

Comment: Are you sure you defined `__MATH_NEON`?  `cosf_neon_hfp` has no `#else` for it, so execution would fall off the end of a non-`void` function.  Also, that inline asm looks bogus if that function inlines.  It's modifying registers without telling the compiler, making unsafe assumptions about what C variables are in which registers.  Have you tried single-stepping through the code to see what actually gets called?  (especially checking the disassembly and looking at registers.)

Comment: Yes, __MATH_NEON is defined in other header file(math_neon.h).I have not tried single-stepping debugging yet and I will try it later. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

use below:

```
float cosf_neon_sfp(float x)
{
    return sinf_neon_sfp(x + M_PI_2);
}
```

should not do 'float xx = x + M_PI_2' in cosf_neon_hfp, maybe should use assemble